# zsh: killed mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"

Tags: npm, terminal, zsh

this is the message when I open my terminal. and whenever I try to write some commands many time it shows like"zhs killed" how can I solve this issue?

Comment: By running the new shell in the terminal with `-x` turned on and analyze the output. What I also would try first is to just open any shell (can also be bash) and do a `zsh -x` and/or a `zsh -l -x`. If you are lucky, the error shows up here too, and you don't have to fiddle around with your terminal configuration.